# How to create common login for 2 Symfony projects on the same server one in Symfony 3.4 and one in Symfony 6.x

Tags: php, symfony

I have a large legacy symfony 3.4 project, on the same server with a new symfony 6 project. Each uses different subdomain. 3.4 already uses many subdomains for different bundles and they share login just fine. But this does not work between 3.4 and 6. Most likely because symfony 6 session structure is slightly different. Anyone had any luck accomplishing that already? All project share one database and all projects store session in file in the same location. At least if someone knows where symphony reads the session, I could probably troubleshoot from there?

Comment: Symfony 3.4 is no longer maintained. Why not upgrade it to 6.3 (the current stable version)?

Comment: Because it's 180k lines of code :), and there is no easy way to upgrade.

Comment: Session structure as such is just serialized user details, it should not depend on the framework version. However, you might be using different bundles/approaches to store it which causes the issue. I would start by checking framework:session settings (https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html#configuration). Notice save_path setting, that's where symfony reads/writes session

Comment: Session does look slightly different, but that might not be a problem. Problem at the moment is that as soon as I switch to the other project session gets overwritten. So my guess is that symfony probably see the session as invalid and wipes its content. Anyone know where in symfony that process takes place so I could troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after 8 hours of working on it, I have to say it can not be done in any civilized way. Serialized objects are different between two versions of symfony and each is unable to deserialize objects from the other session. So much for backwards compatibility.